# Check if bullet point is in list

Tags: python, list

So I am trying to check and see if a bullet point is part of an item in a list by iterating through it with a for loop. I know that, at least in Regex a bullet point is defined as `\u2022`. But don't know how to use this. What I currently have but obviously doesn't work is something like this.

```
list = ['changing. • 5.0 oz.', 'hello', 'dfd','df', 'changing. • 5.0 oz.']
for items in list:
     if "\u2022" in items:
        print('yay')
```

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Is this Python 2 or 3?

Comment: your code works fine for me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In [Python 3 your code will work fine because UTF-8 is the default source code encoding](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html#python-s-unicode-support). If you're going to be working with Unicode a lot, consider switching to Python 3.

In [Python 2, the default is to treat literal strings as sequences of bytes](https://docs.python.org/2.7/howto/unicode.html#python-2-x-s-unicode-support), so you have to explicitly declare which strings are Unicode by prefixing them with `u`.

First, set your source code encoding as UTF-8.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

Then tell Python to encode those strings as Unicode. Otherwise they'll be treated as individual bytes which will lead to odd things like Python thinking the first string has a length of 21 instead of 19.

```
print len(u'changing. • 5.0 oz.')    # 19 characters
print len('changing. • 5.0 oz.')     # 21 bytes
```

This is because [the Unicode code point `U+02022 BULLET` is UTF-8 encoded as three bytes `e2 80 a2`](https://utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl). The first treats it as a single character, the second as three bytes.

Finally, encode the character you're searching for as Unicode. That's either `u'\u2022'` or `u'•'`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

list = [u'changing. • 5.0 oz.', u'hello', u'dfd', u'df', u'changing. • 5.0 oz.']
for item in list:
    if u'•' in item:
        print('yay')
```

Real code probably won't be using constant strings, so you have to make sure that whatever is in `list` is encoded as UTF-8.

Answer (score 3):

Best if you use the `re` (regex) library. Something like this:

```
# import regex library
import re

# compile the regex pattern, using raw string (that's what the r"" is)
bullet_point = re.compile(r"\u2022")
list = ['changing. • 5.0 oz.', 'hello', 'dfd','df', 'changing. • 5.0 oz.']

# search each item in the list
for item in list:
    # search for bullet_point in item
    result = re.search(bullet_point, item)         
    if result:
        print('yay')
```

Comment: While this will work, it's overkill for a simple character search and papers over the encoding problem.

Comment: Very true, I often forget you can encode python as UTF-8